# Get the list of all Teams where a user is member of

Tags: powershell, office365, microsoft-teams

I need to get a list of the user and to what Teams he is a member of.

I know this is possible using :

```
Connect-MgGraph
Get-MgUserJoinedTeam -UserId firstname.lastname@domein.com
```

But I want to check all users at once and see the displayname, email, teams-displayname

Why displayname and/or email of the user, well most users are members of +200 Teams.... (don't ask)

How can I do this?

Comment: What's wrong with your command? What is the actual question?

Comment: I want to make a script that checks all users at once instead of entering the usernames each time.

Comment: Please refer this script - https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSZba.png